# PHP SQLITE INSERT does not insert the record since the record is already in existence but there is no sign or exception to indicate it

Tags: php, sqlite

Concerning SQLite3 and the following PHP code,

I expect when the record exists, I get an Exception to be aware that there was a conflict and the record was not inserted in the database

At the moment I get no Exception and the record is not inserted too! (since the record already exists in the database)
So, how can I be aware that the record was not inserted when everything looks normal?

```
 public function addRecord($mStore_M4_DataClass)
        {
            try 
            {
                $sql = 'INSERT INTO M4(M4_M2,'
                                    . 'M4_M3,'
                                    . 'M4_Barcode,'
                                    . 'M4_Enable,'
                                    . 'M4_Name,'
                                    . 'M4_Price,'
                                    . 'M4_Discount,'
                                    . 'M4_Image1,'
                                    . 'M4_Image2,'
                                    . 'M4_Image3,'
                                    . 'M4_Image4,'
                                    . 'M4_Image5,'
                                    . 'M4_Image6,'
                                    . 'M4_Image7,'
                                    . 'M4_Image8,'
                                    . 'M4_Image9,'
                                    . 'M4_Image10,'
                                    . 'M4_A,'
                                    . 'M4_B,'
                                    . 'M4_C,'
                                    . 'M4_D,'
                                    . 'M4_E,'
                                    . 'M4_F,'
                                    . 'M4_G,'
                                    . 'M4_H,'
                                    . 'M4_I,'
                                    . 'M4_J) '
                        . 'VALUES(:M4_M2,'
                               . ':M4_M3,'
                               . ':M4_Barcode,'
                               . ':M4_Enable,'
                               . ':M4_Name,'
                               . ':M4_Price,'
                               . ':M4_Discount,'
                               . ':M4_Image1,'
                               . ':M4_Image2,'
                               . ':M4_Image3,'
                               . ':M4_Image4,'
                               . ':M4_Image5,'
                               . ':M4_Image6,'
                               . ':M4_Image7,'
                               . ':M4_Image8,'
                               . ':M4_Image9,'
                               . ':M4_Image10,'
                               . ':M4_A,'
                               . ':M4_B,'
                               . ':M4_C,'
                               . ':M4_D,'
                               . ':M4_E,'
                               . ':M4_F,'
                               . ':M4_G,'
                               . ':M4_H,'
                               . ':M4_I,'
                               . ':M4_J)';

                $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute([
                    ':M4_M2'       => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_M2      (),
                    ':M4_M3'       => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_M3      (),
                    ':M4_Barcode'  => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_Barcode (),
                    ':M4_Enable'   => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_Enable  (),
                    ':M4_Name'     => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_Name    (),
                    ':M4_Price'    => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_Price   (),
                    ':M4_Discount' => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_Discount(),
                    ':M4_Image1'   => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_Image1  (),
                    ':M4_Image2'   => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_Image2  (),
                    ':M4_Image3'   => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_Image3  (),
                    ':M4_Image4'   => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_Image4  (),
                    ':M4_Image5'   => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_Image5  (),
                    ':M4_Image6'   => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_Image6  (),
                    ':M4_Image7'   => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_Image7  (),
                    ':M4_Image8'   => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_Image8  (),
                    ':M4_Image9'   => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_Image9  (),
                    ':M4_Image10'  => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_Image10 (),
                    ':M4_A'        => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_A       (),
                    ':M4_B'        => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_B       (),
                    ':M4_C'        => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_C       (),
                    ':M4_D'        => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_D       (),
                    ':M4_E'        => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_E       (),
                    ':M4_F'        => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_F       (),
                    ':M4_G'        => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_G       (),
                    ':M4_H'        => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_H       (),
                    ':M4_I'        => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_I       (),
                    ':M4_J'        => $mStore_M4_DataClass->getM4_J       (),
                ]);

                return TRUE;
            } 
            catch (\PDOException $e) 
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
```

If the record does not exist, it is inserted and the TRUE is returned from this function
If the record already exists, TRUE is returned again!

And the following code is create table code:

```
public function createTable() {
            try 
            {
                $commands = [
                    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS M4 (
                            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                            M4_M2       TEXT,
                            M4_M3       TEXT,
                            M4_Barcode  TEXT,
                            M4_Enable   TEXT,
                            M4_Name     TEXT,
                            M4_Price    TEXT,
                            M4_Discount TEXT,
                            M4_Image1   TEXT,
                            M4_Image2   TEXT,
                            M4_Image3   TEXT,
                            M4_Image4   TEXT,
                            M4_Image5   TEXT,
                            M4_Image6   TEXT,
                            M4_Image7   TEXT,
                            M4_Image8   TEXT,
                            M4_Image9   TEXT,
                            M4_Image10  TEXT,
                            M4_A        TEXT,
                            M4_B        TEXT,
                            M4_C        TEXT,
                            M4_D        TEXT,
                            M4_E        TEXT,
                            M4_F        TEXT,
                            M4_G        TEXT,
                            M4_H        TEXT,
                            M4_I        TEXT,
                            M4_J        TEXT
                            )',
                           'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_positions_title ON M4 (M4_M2,M4_M3,M4_Barcode)'
                ];
                foreach ($commands as $command) {
                    $this->pdo->exec($command);
                }
                return TRUE;
            } 
            catch (\PDOException $e) 
            {
               return FALSE;   
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't generate an exception. From [PDO::exec Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php)

> **Return Values**
>
> PDO::exec() returns the number of rows that were modified or deleted
> by the SQL statement you issued. If no rows were affected, PDO::exec()
> returns 0.
>
> **Warning**
>
> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
> non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on
> Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the
> return value of this function.

The error is also detectable by interrogating [PDO::errorCode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php) and/or [PDO::errorInfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php).

Comment: rowCount() works on this case? if it is not inserted rowCount() is 0 and 1 if it is inserted?

Comment: IME that should work, even though the Note in the [PHP doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) says "_This method returns "0" (zero) with the SQLite driver at all times_". Give it a try.

Comment: It's strange, I do use rowCount() with SQLite all the times and it is working fine!!! while the documentation says SQLite shall not use it!!!

Comment: while in SQLite tutorial says it is working fine:https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-php/update/